# Is it possible to have a temporary copy of MySQL Database?

Tags: php, mysql

I have an application written in PHP and MySQL. Multiple users access this application and make changes to the Database (insert, update, delete). I wish the changes made by each user were not permanent in the original database. Also, I wish that multiple users can access the system at the same time, and their changes do not interfere in the other user's works logged in at the same time.

Is there a way to do this with MySQL? Or do I need another DB tool?

I have been searching for mirroring or replication but this not what I am looking for. Mirroring or replication create a hard copy of my DB. I would like a temporary copy that expires when the users close the web browser.

Comment: Check here : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/210869/creating-a-temporary-copy-of-a-table-with-partitions?rq=1

Comment: Is there a limit on what the changes are / what data ban be changed?

Comment: keep in mind that @AmiraBedhiafi suggestion will take away alot RAM assuming the temporary can be stored in the memory otherwise it will consume alot of diskspace and disk i/o when alot of users are concurrent active on the system..  Creating a "fixed staging" table where you store user changes with record based acces seams a way better approach.. Also you should be able to use javascripts onunload event to detect a browser close or different website load on that event you could notify PHP to remove the users session records.

Comment: @Jonnix No, there is not a limit of changes for now. But it is a thing to think in the future.

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi Thanks. I will check it.

Comment: well you should not have taking the term "fixes staging" literal.. i just meant  a normal fixed table as in `CREATE TABLE record_user_changes ( user_id INT, ....)`  .. the problem with a temporary table `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE .. (...)` is that it will create a temporary table and copy all data form the table foreach client..

Comment: @RaymondNijland About the term "fixed staging" I just Googled it and the results were not what I am looking for. Is there another term that I can search for?

Comment: see mine comment..

Comment: @RaymondNijland Thanks. I think the temporary table is the thing that I want. I was reading about it and I found out that the temporary table only exists while the session is active. In the other hand a fixed table will remains useless in DB after the session ends. But thanks anyway.

Comment: *"I think the temporary table is the thing that I want. I was reading about it and I found out that the temporary table only exists while the session is active"* keep in mind that when the main table is 1 Gb for example the temporary table will most likely make 1 Gb disk based copies foreach client imagine if you have 100 concurrent clients...